# Java 8 lambda and extension of interfaces with abstract class

Tags: java, spring, lambda, java-8

Say I want to declare Spring's `RowMapper`, but not create a dynamic class, but implement an abstract class which implements RowMapper. This is my method signature:

```
SqlProcedure#declareRowMapper(RowMapper<?> rowMapper);
```

CustomRowMapper.java:

```
public abstract class CustomRowMapper<T> implements RowMapper<T> {
    protected A a = new A();
}
```

The old Java way would be to write:

```
sqlProc.declareRowMapper(new CustomRowMapper<Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) {
        a.doSomething(rs, rowNum);
        return new Object();
    }
});
```

Is it possible to achieve the same thing with lambda expressions? I would like to do something like this:

```
sqlProc.declareRowMapper((rs, rowNum) -> {
    a.doSomething(rs, rowNum);
    return new Object();
});
```

But then I would get a compile error saying `a cannot be resolved`. It's because Java sees this as an implementation of the `RowMapper#mapRow` method, not `CustomRowMapper#mapRow`.

How do I tell Java to use my CustomRowMapper instead of RowMapper via lambda expressions? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can extend the functional interface and create one of your own:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface CustomRowMapper<T> implements RowMapper<T> {
    static A a = new A();
}
```

Then, you can pass a lambda, which is the implementation of `CustomRowMapper#mapRow()` method like this:

```
CustomRowMapper myCustomRowMapperLambda = (rs, rowNum) -> {
    a.doSomething(rs, rowNum);
    return new Object();
};
sqlProc.declareRowMapper(myCustomRowMapperLambda);
```

Comment: Thanks - this looks like an acceptable answer. I have also realized that if there is only one object in the CustomRowMapper (like `A` in my example), it perhaps clearer declare it before declaring row mapper, like so: `A a = new A(); sqlProc.declareRowMapper((rs, rowNum) -> { a.doSomething(rs, rowNum); ... });` to avoid unnecessary instantiation if there are a lot of rows to map.

Comment: @nosid, thanks for the note. It's implicitly static, but yes ... to avoid confusion I added the keyword.

Comment: Of course "a" will be one shared instance across all of your Lambdas, so you might want to be careful about this solution. notice that in your original code, A is not static, so each instance of CustomRowMapper has it's own unique instance of A...

Comment: Note that lambda expressions do *not* inherit anything from the functional interface. Since `a` is a `public static` variable, it might get accessed from the lambda expression’s code, but it needs either, be qualified as `CustomRowMapper.a` or you have to add an `import static CustomRowMapper.a;` to allow an unqualified access. So there is no advantage in putting `a` into the `interface`, for the lambda expression it’s not better than any other location, which in turn renders the entire custom `interface` obsolete…

Answer (score 12):

Lambdas can't implement abstract classes. [Here is why](http://www.techempower.com/blog/2013/03/26/everything-about-java-8/).

There is workaround mentioned in the article, but it won't work in your case as you trying to reference object field. What you can do, besides sticking to old-fashion anonymous classes, is to think how to "inject" A into lamda, for example:

- instantiate A object inside lambda;
- create A ouside of lambda scope;
- make A singletone of some sort.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
sqlProc.declareRowMapper((rs, rowNum) -> {
    new A().doSomething(rs, rowNum);
    return new Object();
});
```

You would have to instantiate your Object A. Given the code you show this would not change a thing.

To answer to the more general question not solely relying on example :
Even with the cast you won't access to private variable A, I tend to think that is due to how types of lamdbas are infered.

And in fact I don't think it is whisful for : A lambda should be stateless. (You can make it stateful with the context but it is not something I would recommend).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. @jeremija asks if it's possible to pass a custom implementation of the functional interface without workarounds like this. :)