# Cast java.util.function.Function to Interface

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

*Example*

In this (simplified) example I can create my `MyInterface`-object by using a method reference to `apply`, but casting directly doesn't work.

```
@Test
public void testInterfaceCast(){
    Function<String, Integer> func = Integer::parseInt;

    MyInterface legal = func::apply; // works
    MyInterface illegal = func; // error
}

public interface MyInterface extends Function<String, Integer>{}
```

The second assignment gives the compiler error:

```
incompatible types: Function<String,Integer> cannot be converted to MyInterface
```

*The question*

Can I do some Generics magic, to be able to cast a `Function<T, R>` to an Interface?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what would you do with it?

Comment: I have a case where I use `Function.andThen`, and it returns a `Function` with some ugly complex generics, that I want to abstract away by casting it to an Interface.

Comment: A Function is a Function is a Function. Casting won't change its type.

Comment: Simple casting would not work here? Just try: MyInterface illegal = (MyInterface)func;

Comment: Just a (maybe obvious) remark: You can work around this with `MyInterface legalToo = s -> func.apply(s);` ...

Comment: @Marco13 I actually tried that in my code, but I find that `::apply` is a bit easier to read, if I have to pick between the two.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/tajakobsen/unxml/blob/a761fe141125258a410034b8bc2619fb732c7b79/src/main/java/com/nerdforge/unxml/parsers/builders/ArrayNodeParserBuilder.java#L38) is a link to my code, where I need to use this. (Edit: I had to delete my previous link, since some refactoring made it unavailable).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason `MyInterface illegal = func;` doesn't work, is because `func` is declared as a variable of type `Function<String,Integer>`, which is not a sub-type of `MyInterface`.

The reason why `MyInterface legal = func::apply;` works is the following. You might expect the type of `fun::apply` to be `Function<String,Integer>` as well, but this is not the case. The type of `fun::apply` depends in part on what type the compiler expects. Since you use it in an assignment context, the compiler expects an expressen of type `MyInterface`, and therefore *in that context* `func::apply` is of type `MyInterface`. It is for this reason, that method reference expression can only appear in a assignment contexts, invocation contexts and casting contexts (see the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13)).

Since `Function<String,Integer>` is not a sub-type of `MyInterface`, casting `func` to a `MyInterface` throws a `ClassCastException`. Therefore, the clearest way to convert a `Function<String,Integer>` to a `MyInterface` is to use a method reference, as you already did:

```
MyInterface legal = func::apply;
```

Comment: If OP's `MyInterface` added an extra method (meaning it's no longer a Functional Interface) would `MyInterface legal = func::apply` fail? (As an aside, would it cause a compilation error because `Function` is annotated with `@FunctionalInterface`?)

Answer (score 8):

At the bottom of this is the fact that, in spite of all the pretty syntax which gives such an appearance superficially, Java has not adopted structural types; the rules of Liskov substitutability of *named types* hold as strictly as ever. In your real-life code you call `Function.andThen`, which returns some instance of `Function`, and definitely not an instance of `MyInterface`. So when you write

```
MyInterface legal = func::apply;
```

you'll get another object, which is an instance of `MyInterface`. By contrast, when you write

```
MyInterface illegal = func;
```

you are attempting to assign a reference to the existing instance of `Function` directly to `illegal`, which would violate Liskov substitutability even though it matches the type structurally. No trick can exist to get around this fundamentally; even if Java introduced some new syntactic sugar which would make it *look* like casting, the actual semanticts would still be that of *conversion* (evaluating to another instance).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't compile for the same reason this snippet doesn't compile:

```
Animal animal = new Animal();
Cat x = animal; //illegal assignment
```

i.e. you're implying that every animal *can be* a cat. The compiler has no evidence that the actual super-class instance *will really be a cat* at Runtime and therefore raises an error.

You have to assign `Integer::parseInt` to a `MyInterface` instance:

```
MyInterface func = Integer::parseInt;
MyInterface illegal = func;
```

as `func` is of type `Function<String, Integer>` (i.e. the super-type of `MyInterface`).

Truth is that there's no way to make `Integer::parseInt` of type `MyInterface` at compile-time, [unless assigning it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324013/java-8-lambda-and-extension-of-interfaces-with-abstract-class) to `MyInterface` variable.

Comment: I forgot to write that you can't do that cast either. You get something like:
`InterfaceTest$$Lambda$1/1768883882 cannot be cast to InterfaceTest$MyInterface
java.lang.ClassCastException: InterfaceTest$$Lambda$1/1768883882 cannot be cast to InterfaceTest$MyInterface`